# evaluate expression in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I'm trying to evaluate a string as a formula:

In dplyr it would look like this:

```
dt = data.table(a = 1:10)
expr = 'sum(a)'

dt %>% 
  mutate(b := !!parse_expr(expr))
```

However when I try with data.table I'm getting an error:

```
dt[, b := parse_expr(expr)]
```

> Error in `[.data.table`(dt, , `:=`(b, parse_expr(expr))) : 
>     RHS of assignment is not NULL, not an an atomic vector (see ?is.atomic) and not a list column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `parse_expr`, `eval(parse` can be used

```
dt[, b := eval(parse(text = expr))]
```

Or wrap with `eval` on `parse_expr` as the `!!` is doing the evaluation in `tidyverse`

```
dt[, b := eval(rlang::parse_expr(expr)) ]
```

Comment: @R.M.  With `rlang` and tidyverse, they use a consistent pattern with `!!`, but that wouldn't work outside the tidyverse env or else you may need `as_mapper`